# Docker install nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I new with docker and want to install `nginx` inside my container for redirection on external ip

my goal is send request to  `http://localhost:3010/api/v1/service`
inside docker and it should redirect me to my `http://192.168.99.1:3010/api/v1/service`

```
http://192.168.99.1:3010 -it my rails server running
```

Or maybe i totally wrong with my idea?

i try to do it `RUN yum install nginx` but i have got

```
ERROR: Service 'my_service_name' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yum install nginx' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest


USER root
ENV TERM dumb

RUN yum -y install wget && \
    wget https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/download/v0.15/remote_syslog_linux_amd64.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf ./remote_syslog*.tar.gz && \
    cd remote_syslog && \
    cp ./remote_syslog /usr/local/bin && \
    yum -y install postgresql && yum clean all

ADD customization/DigiCertCA.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/DigiCertCA.pem
RUN update-ca-trust extract


# install nginx
RUN yum install nginx
# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
# Set the default command to execute when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start


CMD ["find / -type f -exec ls -l {} \;"]
CMD ["chmod 666 customization/*.properties"]

ADD customization /opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/
COPY customization/WebService.* /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/

ADD newrelic /opt/jboss/wildfly/newrelic/

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/execute.sh"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: What is your base image? Can you post your entire dockerfile?

Comment: There's also the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) you can use. You can extend that and add your own config files and be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't add the nginx repository to your container.
Try adding this step before you run `yum install nginx`
`RUN yum -y install epel-release`

Two extra tips - 
1. Install yum packages with the -y flag, otherwise they will fail for lack of user input.
2. Try to put all of your package install commands in one `RUN` command, to reduce layers in your image.
For example, I would Nginx to your current Dockerfile like so -

```
RUN yum -y install wget && \
    wget https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/download/v0.15/remote_syslog_linux_amd64.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf ./remote_syslog*.tar.gz && \
    cd remote_syslog && \
    cp ./remote_syslog /usr/local/bin && \
    yum -y install postgresql \
    yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y install nginx && yum clean all
```

Comment: Great to hear. You should take @R0MANARMY comment as well. He's right - using the official nginx image is the best practice for such a use case.